# Converting multiband-image to attribute table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a multiband-image with 12 Bands (monthly summed rain values, float)

How can I convert the multiband image into an attribute table in ArcGIS / ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: What would the attribute table look like? One row for each month with total rainfall?

Comment: More like each band i.e. each monthly rainfall in columns,
spatial information / Pixel ID in Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arcpy, pandas and numpy modules. Example with 3 band Sentinel image, adjust input raster and output csv and execute in python window:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raster = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\Sentinel2_2018_miniclip.tif'

arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster)
series = []
for dimension in range(arr.shape[0]):
    series.append(pd.Series(arr[dimension].ravel(), name='month_{0}'.format(dimension+1)))
df = pd.concat(series, axis=1)
df.to_csv(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\sent2data.csv', index=False)
```

Example of csv file. Then convert to whatever format you want using TableToTable etc.:

```
month_1,month_2,month_3
89,30,55
81,28,55
80,25,48
79,29,50
81,30,51
86,30,55
93,29,55
97,33,63
101,35,64
98,34,60
```

Comment: Great! Thats exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot =)

PS: Code is missing the closing bracket ")" at the end - I'm still new, and I don't know how to edit your answer.

Comment: Nice! Make sure correct band ends up in correct month column.

Comment: Double-Checked - works fine so far :)
Thanks